# Firestore Disable Cache - Swift Singleton

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, singleton

When creating a swift singleton that has a Firestore property, how do you set it not to cache.  For some reason, I can't get my init to work.  Keep getting a complaint that you can't use an instance member? (being told instance member 'db' cannot be used on type 'HCFireStoreService'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

```
class HCFireStoreService {
    
    var db = Firestore.firestore()

    static let instance: HCFireStoreService = {
        let sharedInstance = HCFireStoreService()
        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
        db.settings = settings
        return sharedInstance
    }()
}
```

Comment: Is `db2.settings` supposed to be `db.settings`?

Comment: @liquid yep, my bad.. I tried to create a db instance inside that as well and deleted the wrong line.  Edited the original code snippet.  Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore can be tricky to configure with the singleton pattern if you aren’t careful about order of execution. I would avoid the singleton pattern with Firestore but if you want it to work, here is one way:

```
class HCFireStoreService {
    static let shared = HCFireStoreService()
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    private init() {}
    
    func configure() {
        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
        db.settings = settings
    }
    
    func someMethod() {
        db.document("yyy/xxx").getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
            print("xxx")
        }
    }
}
```

To get this to work, you must instantiate this class (first use of the shared instance) after you've configured Firebase and before you've interfaced with the database. Therefore, if you're configuring Firestore in the App Delegate, then simply configure the singleton thereafter and then you are free to use its methods.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    HCFireStoreService.shared.configure()
}

HCFireStoreService.shared.someMethod()
```

Comment: thanks for the info!   I have it as db to be property as this entire class is responsible for all of my calls to FireStore to retrieve data.

Comment: My only question is how to you then access the db object in other methods inside of the HCFireStoreService class?

Comment: @ liquid , 

so when I did that I get back the original message of :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRIllegalStateException', reason: 'Firestore instance has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only set settings before calling any other methods on a Firestore instance.' upon the first execution of HCFireStoreService.instance.someMethod()

Comment: @justdan0227 are you configuring these settings anywhere else?

Comment: @ liquid , nope, just in that init.  Not sure why it's giving me such grief.  Your suggestion should work.

Comment: @ liquid , thanks!  That did it.  I swear I tried every combination!